# Error when Retrieving a List Result with an Interface Projection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I'm new to Spring Boot and Hibernate, and I need your help. I have two entities, Author and Book (onetoMany) in my Spring Boot application. I'm receiving results that don't match my expectations, and the results I'm getting are as follows

// Received Result

```json
[
  {
    "books": null,
    "authorId": 1,
    "authorName": "Ahmaha"
  },
  {
    "books": null,
    "authorId": 1,
    "authorName": "Ahmaha"
  },
  {
    "books": null,
    "authorId": 1,
    "authorName": "Ahmaha"
  }
]
```

// Desired Result

```json
{
      authorId: 1,
      authorName: 'Ahmaha',
      books: [
        {title: 'title1', pages: 'pages1'},
        {title: 'title2', pages: 'pages2'},
      ]
}
```

// Entity Author:

```java
package com.example.demo.Author;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Book> books;
}
```

// Entity Book

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private int pages;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="author_id")
    private Author author;
}
```

// Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT a.id AS authorId, a.name AS authorName, b.title AS title, b.pages AS pages " +
            "FROM Author a INNER JOIN Book b ON a.id = b.author.id WHERE a.id=:idUser")

    List<AuthorWithBooksProjection> findAuthorsWithBooks(@Param("idUser") Long id);
}
```

// Service

```java
@Service
public class AuthorService {

    private final AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorService(AuthorRepository authorRepository) {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }

    public List<AuthorWithBooksProjection> getAuthorsWithBooks(Long idUser) {
        return authorRepository.findAuthorsWithBooks(idUser);
    }
}
```

// Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authors")
public class AuthorController {

    private final AuthorService authorService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorController(AuthorService authorService) {
        this.authorService = authorService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/withBooks/{id}")
    public List<AuthorWithBooksProjection> getAuthorsWithBooks(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long idUser) {
        return authorService.getAuthorsWithBooks(idUser);
    }
}
```

// My Projection

```java
public interface AuthorWithBooksProjection {
    Long getAuthorId();

    String getAuthorName();

    List<BookProjection> getBooks();
}

interface BookProjection {
    String getBookTitle();

    int getBookPages();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By updating the query to use the `books` attribute instead of the separate fields, you can get a better result (although not the desired one though).

```
    @Query("SELECT a.id AS authorId, a.name AS authorName, a.books AS books " +
            "FROM Author a WHERE a.id=:idUser")
    List<AuthorWithBooksProjection> findAuthorsWithBooks(@Param("idUser") Long id);
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "books": [
            {
                "title": "title1",
                "pages": 1
            }
        ],
        "authorName": "Ahmaha",
        "authorId": 1
    },
    {
        "books": [
            {
                "title": "title2",
                "pages": 2
            }
        ],
        "authorName": "Ahmaha",
        "authorId": 1
    }
]
```

This solves part of your problem (output is not null), but now it boils down to merging the two results as one.

For those willing to help solve this last issue, I created a sample repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-hibernate-projection)